# Mapping variable to hexagon size with geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know if its possible to map to hexagon size with ggplot?  Size is listed as an argument in the [geom_hex documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_hex.html), but there are no examples of size mapping in [stat_hexbin](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_binhex.html), so this just seems to relate to bin size.

Take for example:

```
ggplot(economics, aes(x=uempmed, y=unemploy)) + geom_hex()
```

[image]

But looking for instance at population distribution (below) it might be useful to map binned mean population to hexagon size, but I've not found a formula for this (if one exists).

```
ggplot(economics, aes(x=uempmed, y=unemploy, col=pop)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt that this is implemented. If you think about the algorithm for that, it seems quite complicated to do and would probably require an iterating procedure.

Comment: @Roland, I'm confused why you think that. If you determine the bin size externally, you can then choose the size of the hexagons independently (although they will have an upperlimit without overlapping).

Comment: Well, if you want the size depend on binned mean population, you first have to bin with a fixed size. Then calculate the binned mean population. Than rebin based on this, which could change the binned mean population. Repeat.

Comment: The bin tessellation is, as I understand, independent of subsequent stat calculations, in which `geom_hex` assumes a density function of points on xy plane. In principle couldn't ggplot devs tweak the same tessellation to automatically bin population, perhaps with an `aes(size=pop)` addition to geom_hex / stat_binhex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the official answer is that ggplot does not have functionality to map to hexagon area. But as you can see a workaround solution is possible, now posted in a [gist at github](https://gist.github.com/geotheory/5748388).

[image]

Comment: were you planning on enlightening the rest of us to this work around?

Comment: Holy 339 lines workaround, building everything from scratch... Any simpler solution since this was posted?

Comment: 338 actually ;) I'd like to think someone had ggproto'd this by now. Any idea anyone?