# R, ggplot2 and a world map with points un hexagone cell

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, hexagonal-tiles

I have a data frame like

```
 X                date         lon      lat 
1 1 2014-01-08 23:50:13 -116.576504 53.93327
2 2 2014-01-08 23:35:50          NA       NA
3 3 2014-01-08 23:06:33          NA       NA
4 4 2014-01-08 23:06:07  -76.670200 39.38100
5 5 2014-01-08 22:44:37  -77.436048 37.54072
6 6 2014-01-08 22:35:56    7.189811 43.67342
```

and I would like to map it on a world shape file,  but if my points could be in hexagon... with ggplot2 .. it will be great!
I'm not abble to use geom_hex ... it doesn't make what I whant ... 
[Something like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894460/mapping-variable-to-hexagon-size-with-geom-hex) but with a world map below. A complexe way is on the slide 22 of [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/tjagger/r-spatial-analysis-using-sp) , I have tried

```
wp<-ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=word.df,aes(long,lat,group=group))+
  geom_path(color="white")+
  geom_hex(data=cleanTwittes,aes(lon,lat))+
  coord_equal()
```

but I'have this error : 'Erreur dans if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : '

thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find something :-)

```
wp<-ggplot()+
   geom_polygon(data=word.df,aes(long,lat,group=group))+
   geom_hex(data=cleanTwittes,aes(lon,lat),bins = 55,alpha=8/10)+
   theme_bw()+
   labs(title = paste(nbTwittes,"twittes entre",minT,"et",maxT, "sur 'terroir'"))
   coord_equal()
```

It make a map not so bad 
[image]

But if you have some sugestion ...